# ubuntu - cannot run qtcreator or other programs

Tags: caching, ubuntu-16.04, ram

I'm not an advanced user of Linux/Ubuntu.

yesterday, I thought it would be great to clean ram and cache as cleaning them could make my computer run faster. So, I did this as per this website.
[tecmint link](https://www.tecmint.com/clear-ram-memory-cache-buffer-and-swap-space-on-linux/)

> ***sudo -i sync; echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches sync; echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches sync; echo 3 > /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches
> exit***

Now, when I run C++ code in Qt Creator, it's not compiling and giving back in application output this:

> ***"Starting /home/jonmay/Documents/CPP_lessons/build-boqian_lessons-Desktop-Debug/boqian_lessons...
> Cannot set up communication channel: Cannot create temporary directory
> "/tmp/QtCreator.d13950": No space left on device
> /home/jonmay/Documents/CPP_lessons/build-boqian_lessons-Desktop-Debug/boqian_lessons
> exited with code -1"***

I see the 'No space left on device'. So, I check the properties on computer. It is listing 0 byte free.
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sn2XV.png]
Netbeans is also not compiling.

Comment: Clean up and remove some stuff you have no room left on this partition.

Comment: @GwenM :  How do i check the stuffs and how to remove them? doing the following show some stuffs, But i m not sure what they are and how or which to remove them. I m worried if the system will crash if i remove the wrong stuff.

Comment: Well what do you do with that partition? Is it just a dev environment? Because 14Gb is not much, it's pretty much Ubuntu + some packages, you would have to size up the partition/HD.

Comment: @GwenM : Thanks for your help.. I have been doing s"udo apt-get autoclean & sudo apt-get autoremove". but it didn't work. Finally I came across "sudo apt clean" and after doing it, it now frees up the space and is now working..